# Tipo de gráficos

Tags: java, swing

Eu gostaria de saber, se existe algum componente ou biblioteca que gera um "gráfico" semelhante com este. Eu li a documentação do `JFreeChart`, e lá existem alguns tipo de gráficos, porém nada próximo deste.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que esse "gráfico" faz, é mover esse indicador *(essa barra preta com o 28,40)* de acordo com valores digitados em um campo.

Comment: Da uma olhada em https://www.highcharts.com/demo Se não tiver exatamente o que você quer, certamente terá um similar que te atende.

Comment: Dentro do Java, o mais próximo que consigo imaginar |é fazer um [Jslider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) customizado. Só não sei se o Jslider permite esse nível de customização em cores.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer algo próximo usando  o Jslider mais tarde.

Comment: Cara, parece que não tem como fazer isso sem criar o componente do zero. Mas como alternativa, deixo essa resposta do soen, veja se serve para o seu proposito:https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867268/5524514

Comment: @diegofm já é um ponto de partida, muito obrigado !

Comment: Qualquer coisa que precise de ajuda nesse código do soen, avisa ai que posso tentar ajudar ;)